# ADB over wifi goes away after unplugging usb

Tags: wi-fi, adb

connect the usb to your phone open the cmd and type:

```
adb devices
Huawie Mate 8                   device
```

and it gives something like this. This is the device connected over usb.Now type

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.43.1:5555
```

type adb devices again
    adb devices
    Huawie Mate 8                   device
    192.168.43.1:5555               device
and it works perfectly.

The problem is:
as soon as the usb is plugged out.
and after typing:
adb devices
List of attached devices

and the list is empty 
try:

```
adb connect 192.168.43.1

unable to connect to 192.168.43.1:5555 cannot connect to `192.168.43.1:5555 : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.(10061)`
```

I dont know what to do tried revoke usb from developer settings.

Comment: Is the phone definitely on the same Wi-Fi network as the PC?

Comment: Hi.thanks for the reply.Yes they were but there was a FireWall installed on my phone which didn't support LAN it could only let mobile data and wifi but it had no idea about LAN and blocked all the data.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it may be this the case, or it may be helpful, but I got the same message, and it worked if I enable adb via WiFi with the command 'adb tcpip 5555' (from the PC) when the PC is connected to the phone hotspot but the phone is NOT connected to the internet (i.e., 3G is deactivated). 
In short, I did the following:

1. Plug the device via USB
2. Restart the phone
3. Disable phone data
4. Enable phone hotspot
5. (adb usb)
6. adb tcpip 5555
7. Unplug the device
8. adb connect 192.168.43.1:5555

After that, I reactivated 3G on the phone, and I had both the internet hotspot and the adb connection, at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you have the same problem,It's probably the firewall on the computer or on the phone,Make sure first disable both and try again if worked get another firewall or adjust the ones you had to get them working.