# I have my android connected to my pc via a wifi hot spot. How do I enable usb debbuging through the adb ? What is the commands?

Tags: adb, usb

What are the commands in ADB to enable USB debugging?

I have my android connected to my pc via a wifi hot spot. How do I enable usb debbuging through the adb ? What is the commands?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/197914 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=za.co.henry.hsu.adbwirelessbyhenry

Answer (score 1):

Enable **developer options** and **USB debugging** of your phone:

1. Open **Settings**, then select **About**.
2. Tap on **Build number** seven times.
3. Go back, and select **Developer options**.
4. Scroll down, and check the **Android debugging** or **USB debugging** entry under **Debugging**.
5. Plug your phone into your computer.

For debugging **Android studio** via WiFi install **Wifi Adb Ultimate** plugin
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9207-wifi-adb-ultimate

Comment: consider improvement include *adb tcpip 5555;
adb connect <ip>* for a complete answer

Comment: If you want to do this manually, it can be like usethe4ce answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi